# How can i find my syntax error in a select query partuculary with dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the error derived from the query;

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds  to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ':date,dob)) AS age FROM player WHERE bowling_skill='Legbreak
>   googly') AS derived' at line 1

Query:

```
SELECT player_name, 
       age AS player_age 
FROM   (SELECT player_id, 
               player_name, 
               Date_part('year', Age('2018-02-12' :: DATE, dob)) AS age 
        FROM   player 
        WHERE  bowling_skill = 'Legbreak googly') AS derived4 
WHERE  derived4.age >= 28 
ORDER  BY derived4.age DESC, 
          player_name ASC;
```

Comment: Step 1: format your SQL so that you can actually read it... Done.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':date,dob)) AS age FROM player WHERE bowling_skill='Legbreak googly') AS derived' at line 1

Comment: Yes, I see that.  It's in your post.

Comment: Perhaps you should do what it says and check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use.

Comment: HINT: the error message reads: *near `':date,dob)) AS ...`*. So the error is near `':date,dob))...`.

Comment: You are using MariaDB but your code is Postgresql code.

Answer (score 1):

Use MariaDB syntax, not PostgreSQL's one:

```
SELECT player_name, 
       age AS player_age 
FROM   (SELECT player_id, 
               player_name, 
               TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dob,cast('2018-02-12' as DATE)) AS age 
        FROM   player 
        WHERE  bowling_skill = 'Legbreak googly') AS derived4 
WHERE  derived4.age >= 28 
ORDER  BY derived4.age DESC, 
          player_name ASC;
```

Comment: What does CAST do?

Comment: It converts string to date in this case. I used it because I wasn't sure that the functionTIMESTAMPDIFF works with varchar datatype